# Is there anyway to pass in a variable in constructor when loading a model?

Tags: php, codeigniter, constructor

I am trying to load an model, and pass in a variable in the constructor  but couldn't find a solution to achieve this. Would anyone have a solution to this issue? Below is my code. Thanks!

```
    $this->load->model(["client/HiredFreelancers_Model"]);
```

Model File

```
class HiredFreelancers_Model extends CI_Model {  

  private $proj_id;

    public function __construct($proj_id)
    {
        $this->proj_id = $proj_id;
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP & Codeigniter - how to pass parameters to a model?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149098/php-codeigniter-how-to-pass-parameters-to-a-model)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not do this. As far as I know this does not go along with the MVC model.

One question is: do you need a model or could you create a library instead?

A solution would be to use a init-function that you call after loading the model. The better MVC approach would be to pass your parameter when calling functions on the loaded model.

This answered question might help too: [CodeIgniter: How to pass variables to a model while loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15815381/codeigniter-how-to-pass-variables-to-a-model-while-loading)